iPhone tethering unsuccessful from “Self-assigned IP”
Something broke with my hotspot tethering from my iPhone. The internet is never successfully handed off despite the devices being connected and tethered to each other. Something feels like it broke as a result of a device renaming that has my MacBook seeing the iPhone under its old name iphone13 which eventually gets replaced by the new iPhone name AttTest2. Tethering to an iPad over WiFi is also unsuccessful as is USB tethering. How can this be fixed?

Here are some screen shots showing what I’m seeing from the MacBook.
Here is the Personal Hotspot Notification Available notification showing the old device name being detected by the MacBook.

When I look at the WiFi popup the old device name shows up twice mysteriously enough.

Then once the tethering completes the new phone name displays alongside the old name.

Here’s another view going the System Settings route, you can see the old name listed for the Personal Hotspots section.

Then attempting to connect to the device you see the old name progressing when establishing the connection.

And here’s what displays once the connected state has been reached.

And finally here’s the signature that internet sharing never succeeds. You find the text “Self-assigned IP” present when viewing the details for the WiFi connection.


Linking to several other instances seen in the wild

2014-05-11 https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/iphone-tethering-doesnt-work.1733628/?post=19145601#post-19145601
2019-04-08 https://arstechnica.com/civis/threads/self-assigned-ip-woes-with-personal-hotspot-help.1450281/
2022-08-22 https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254133937
2022-11-14 https://www.reddit.com/r/macbookair/comments/yvfzcq/still_cant_connect_to_hotspot/
2024-01-11 https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/194gcu0/personal_hotspot_dhcp_fails/


Have you by any chance rebooted the phone since this started? If not, please do that and try again to connect.

I would turn off Bluetooth and WiFi on both devices, power both off, power on the phone and change the tethering on the phone after enabling Bluetooth and WiFi there. Then power up the Mac and turn on Bluetooth and then WiFi and test.

@bmike thank you I tried the steps. It did trigger something new this time when I changed the name on the iPhone, it tickled the MacBook to need to enter a new password for the hotspot and it showed up with the new name I had put on the phone the first time. The phone got the notification to allow the hotspot connection which I permitted but things are still winding up with self-assigned IP in the end however. I’ll make a second attempt to repeat again and see if something changes.
